# Java resize double buffer

Tags: java, image, applet, awt, buffer

Currently, I have a `Applet` running with a while loop inside of it which does two things.

- It calls `tick()`
- Then it calls `render(buffer.getGraphics(), getGraphics)`.

The buffer is a double buffering image I created by doing the following:

```
if(buffer == null)
{
        Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        buffer = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration().createCompatibleVolatileImage(d.width, d.height);
}
```

Now this works fine, the only problem is when I call `setSize()` of the applet and `JFrame`, the new added pixels are just grayed out. Currently I am just creating a new buffer every time the size is changed, but this causes a flickering effect. Anyone know of a way in which I can reuse the existing while using the new area that is added? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> ..problem is when I call `setSize()` of the applet..

That is not something that code should do.  An applet's size is set in the HTML that loads it.

To fix the problem, remove the code that sets the size.

Comment: I removed it `super.setSize()` but the problem is still there. It seems to have changed nothing.

Comment: I'm pretty sure its something to do with the rendering of the image, for example if I render a rectangle to the `Graphics` of the applet, it fills the entire screen.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).